# Could stratospheric aerosol injection be used to fine-tune climate locally?

Tags: geoengineering

I have seen that stratospheric aerosol injection could potentially be used to combat global warming. My question is whether it would be possible to e.g. inject aerosols at different rates in different places in order to adjust climate locally, or if it necessarily has global effects. I.e. would it be possible/feasiable to, for example, stop any climate warming completely in location A, but allow some moderate climate warming in location B.

Answer (score 1):

I think the analogy would be large volcanic eruptions - 1991 Mount Pinatubo for instance. Volcanic eruptions which locally [spew large amounts of light-scattering aerosols into the stratosphere](https://www.science.org/content/article/thanks-volcanoes-earth-cooler-expected-due-recent-eruptions) don't remain there long due to the earth's weather and eventually contribute to global effects.

Dipping into SciFi speculation, if you had a constant source of injection into the stratosphere upwind of a specific location, I would think that location's climate would be modified, but the effect would most certainly continue on downwind - perhaps eventually globally?